# Extend IRB to allow for "filtering" not found methods to a method of my choice?

Tags: ruby, irb

On IRB startup I load a lot of custom files, modules and classes to enhance it.

There is one class I have which would help me a lot but I dont know how to call it automatically. Automatically in this context means: When I start IRB, and when I type something which is not a method or a variable, I would like to call a custom method of my own choosing.

I know loosely that this can be done via either a `rescue`, or with `method_missing`, but I am not sure which one to do either. Can someone show me how to invoke a method in IRB (or irbrc) if I type a method that is unknown to IRB, like "foo"?

Answer (score 2):

I'd choose a different approach:

- put all methods you need into a Module instead of a Class
- have Object `include` this module
- start irb with foo.rb to always automagically load your definitions

foo.rb:

```
module Foo
  def my_method
    puts "aye"
  end
end


class Object
  include Foo
end
```

Now, whenever you type `my_method` in irb, it will call your method.

Comment: Hmm ok but I would need to know what methods I can call. But I don't always know that, like take a method "foolalalblee" and another one "lililalala" (ok, made up examples, but you get the idea, it takes a long time to define them all) Instead, I would like to delegate the methods that I do not know how to handle to a specialized class - actually, I only need to call one method (the missing one), and them from there decide what to do with the input. Sometimes the input should error out, sometimes it should instead pass towards another class.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it would get annoying really quickly, but here's how you do it. Add this to your `.irbrc`:

```
def self.method_missing (name, *args, &block)                                   
  puts "#{name} is not a method, ya goof"                                       
end
```

Obviously, change the contents of the method definition to change what happens when missing methods are caught.

Now whenever you call a method on the `main` object in irb, it catches the missing method.

```
>> foo
foo is not a method, ya goof
=> nil
```

That's just for top-level method calls. If you want to catch *every* missing method call ever, add this instead:

```
class Object
  def method_missing (name, *args, &block)
    puts "#{self.class}##{name} is not a method, ya goof"
  end
end
```

Keep in mind, this is going to reveal to you a lot of method calls that are failing that you probably don't even know about.

```
$ irb
String#to_int is not a method, ya goof
>> foo
NilClass#to_ary is not a method, ya goof
Object#foo is not a method, ya goof
=> nil
>> [].bar
Array#bar is not a method, ya goof
=> nil
```

I don't think this is going to be something you want to live with in the long run, but this is how to do it. Knock yourself out!

Comment: This is almost perfect. There is one question I have though: where is the original error message? For instance, if I type "foo" in irb, I get NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object, but when I use method_missing, that error seems to have disappeared completely.

Comment: You can throw a `super` (no parentheses) at the very end of the method definition if you want the normal NoMethodError to be re-raised.